# Calculation based on list elements

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop, apply

I have a `list` of countries, different modules numbered 0-6 as list elements, and countries' links `list$Value` in respective modules. I also have a dataframe `modules` that specifies what module a country belongs to and their total number of links (total degree centrality). See reproducible examples below.

I would like to write a function that divides each value for respective country and module in `list` by the country's `modules@Degree`, and sum them, as in this equation:

[image]

How can I achieve this with the list elements that I have? My expected output is a dataframe with the result of this calculation for each country. Any help would be very appreciated!

Reproducible example:

```
list <- 
list(Afghanistan = c(`2` = 1L, `3` = 4L, `6` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Albania = c(`2` = 2L, `3` = 1L, `4` = 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA
), Algeria = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 3L, `3` = 4L, `4` = 3L, NA, NA, 
NA), Angola = c(`2` = 2L, `3` = 2L, `4` = 3L, `5` = 1L, NA, NA, 
NA), Antigua.and.Barbuda = c(`1` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), Argentina = c(`0` = 2L, `1` = 12L, `2` = 29L, `3` = 17L, `4` = 26L, 
`5` = 1L, NA), Armenia = c(`2` = 1L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Aruba = c(`1` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Australia = c(`0` = 2L, 
`1` = 3L, `2` = 1L, `4` = 4L, NA, NA, NA), Austria = c(`1` = 4L, 
`2` = 2L, `3` = 7L, `4` = 23L, `6` = 1L, NA, NA), Azerbaijan = c(`3` = 3L, 
`4` = 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Bahrain = c(`2` = 2L, `3` = 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Bangladesh = c(`0` = 1L, `1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, 
`3` = 4L, `4` = 3L, NA, NA), Barbados = c(`1` = 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Belarus = c(`3` = 5L, `4` = 15L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Belgium = c(`1` = 3L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 6L, `4` = 22L, `5` = 1L, 
NA, NA), Belize = c(`1` = 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Benin = c(`2` = 2L, 
`3` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Bhutan = c(`3` = 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Bolivia..Plurinational.State.of. = c(`0` = 1L, `1` = 3L, 
`2` = 5L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA), Bosnia.and.Herzegovina = c(`2` = 1L, 
`3` = 1L, `4` = 11L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Botswana = c(`2` = 3L, 
`5` = 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Brazil = c(`0` = 2L, `1` = 13L, 
`2` = 22L, `3` = 18L, `4` = 23L, `5` = 1L, NA), Brunei.Darussalam = c(`2` = 2L, 
`3` = 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Bulgaria = c(`1` = 4L, `2` = 3L, 
`3` = 6L, `4` = 25L, NA, NA, NA), Burkina.Faso = c(`2` = 4L, 
`4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Burundi = c(`5` = 4L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), C.te.d.Ivoire = c(`2` = 7L, `3` = 1L, `4` = 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Cambodia = c(`0` = 3L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 2L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Cameroon = c(`2` = 2L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Canada = c(`0` = 2L, `1` = 15L, `2` = 6L, `3` = 10L, `4` = 19L, 
NA, NA), Central.African.Republic = c(`5` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Chile = c(`0` = 1L, `1` = 6L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 4L, `4` = 7L, 
NA, NA), China = c(`0` = 2L, `1` = 4L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 13L, 
NA, NA), China..Hong.Kong.SAR = c(`0` = 2L, `1` = 1L, `3` = 2L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), China..Macao.SAR = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), China..Taiwan.Province.of = c(`0` = 3L, `1` = 3L, `2` = 1L, 
`3` = 5L, `4` = 10L, NA, NA), Colombia = c(`0` = 1L, `1` = 4L, 
`2` = 2L, `3` = 5L, `4` = 4L, NA, NA), Congo = c(`2` = 2L, `4` = 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Costa.Rica = c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 2L, 
`4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA), Croatia = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 3L, 
`4` = 23L, NA, NA, NA), Cuba = c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 2L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Cyprus = c(`2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, `4` = 8L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Czechia = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 4L, `4` = 21L, 
NA, NA, NA), Democratic.People.s.Republic.of.Korea = c(`3` = 2L, 
`4` = 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Democratic.Republic.of.the.Congo = c(`2` = 1L, 
`3` = 1L, `5` = 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Denmark = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, 
`3` = 4L, `4` = 21L, NA, NA, NA), Dominican.Republic = c(`1` = 2L, 
`2` = 1L, `3` = 4L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA), Ecuador = c(`0` = 2L, 
`1` = 3L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 2L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA), Egypt = c(`0` = 1L, 
`1` = 2L, `2` = 6L, `3` = 6L, `4` = 13L, NA, NA), El.Salvador = c(`1` = 5L, 
`2` = 1L, `3` = 2L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA), Eritrea = c(`3` = 2L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Estonia = c(`3` = 2L, `4` = 8L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Eswatini = c(`2` = 2L, `5` = 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Ethiopia = c(`2` = 2L, `3` = 2L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Finland = c(`2` = 1L, `3` = 2L, `4` = 13L, NA, NA, NA, NA
), France = c(`0` = 1L, `1` = 6L, `2` = 9L, `3` = 16L, `4` = 30L, 
`6` = 1L, NA), Gabon = c(`2` = 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Gambia = c(`2` = 3L, 
`3` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Georgia = c(`2` = 1L, `3` = 5L, 
`4` = 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Germany = c(`1` = 4L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 10L, 
`4` = 26L, NA, NA, NA), Ghana = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 3L, `3` = 1L, 
`5` = 1L, NA, NA, NA), Greece = c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 3L, 
`4` = 17L, `6` = 1L, NA, NA), Grenada = c(`1` = 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Guatemala = c(`1` = 4L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 1L, 
NA, NA, NA), Guinea = c(`2` = 3L, `3` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), Guinea.Bissau = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Guyana = c(`1` = 3L, `3` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Haiti = c(`1` = 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Honduras = c(`1` = 5L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 2L, 
`4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA), Hungary = c(`1` = 3L, `2` = 4L, `3` = 13L, 
`4` = 31L, `6` = 3L, NA, NA), India = c(`0` = 3L, `1` = 6L, `2` = 10L, 
`3` = 14L, `4` = 7L, NA, NA), Indonesia = c(`0` = 3L, `1` = 3L, 
`2` = 3L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA), Iran..Islamic.Republic.of. = c(`2` = 1L, 
`3` = 6L, `4` = 13L, `6` = 1L, NA, NA, NA), Iraq = c(`2` = 3L, 
`3` = 4L, `4` = 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Ireland = c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 1L, 
`3` = 4L, `4` = 20L, NA, NA, NA), Israel = c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 1L, 
`3` = 4L, `4` = 7L, NA, NA, NA), Italy = c(`1` = 4L, `2` = 4L, 
`3` = 6L, `4` = 24L, NA, NA, NA), Jamaica = c(`1` = 4L, `2` = 1L, 
`3` = 1L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA), Japan = c(`0` = 2L, `1` = 5L, 
`2` = 1L, `3` = 6L, `4` = 10L, NA, NA), Jordan = c(`1` = 1L, 
`2` = 5L, `3` = 7L, `4` = 5L, NA, NA, NA), Kazakhstan = c(`3` = 4L, 
`4` = 6L, `6` = 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Kenya = c(`2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, 
`4` = 1L, `5` = 5L, NA, NA, NA), Kuwait = c(`2` = 2L, `3` = 4L, 
`4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Kyrgyzstan = c(`3` = 1L, `4` = 2L, 
`6` = 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Lao.People.s.Democratic.Republic = c(`0` = 1L, 
`4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Latvia = c(`3` = 2L, `4` = 8L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Lebanon = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 5L, 
`4` = 11L, `6` = 1L, NA, NA), Lesotho = c(`2` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Liberia = c(`2` = 2L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Libya = c(`2` = 2L, `3` = 2L, `4` = 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Lithuania = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 5L, `4` = 16L, NA, 
    NA, NA), Luxembourg = c(`4` = 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Madagascar = c(`2` = 1L, `4` = 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Malawi = c(`2` = 1L, 
    `5` = 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Malaysia = c(`0` = 2L, `1` = 1L, 
    `2` = 3L, `3` = 4L, `4` = 2L, NA, NA), Mali = c(`2` = 2L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Malta = c(`4` = 11L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Mauritania = c(`2` = 2L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), Mexico = c(`1` = 12L, `2` = 5L, `3` = 7L, `4` = 15L, 
    NA, NA, NA), Mongolia = c(`3` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), Montenegro = c(`4` = 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Morocco = c(`1` = 2L, 
    `2` = 2L, `3` = 5L, `4` = 7L, NA, NA, NA), Mozambique = c(`2` = 1L, 
    `5` = 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Myanmar = c(`0` = 2L, `3` = 3L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Namibia = c(`2` = 2L, `5` = 1L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Nepal = c(`2` = 2L, `3` = 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), Netherlands = c(`1` = 3L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 7L, `4` = 22L, 
    NA, NA, NA), New.Zealand = c(`1` = 3L, `3` = 1L, `4` = 10L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Nicaragua = c(`1` = 4L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 2L, 
    `4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA), Niger = c(`2` = 3L, `3` = 1L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Nigeria = c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 2L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), North.Macedonia = c(`2` = 1L, `4` = 8L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Norway = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 3L, 
    `4` = 11L, NA, NA, NA), Oman = c(`2` = 3L, `3` = 4L, `4` = 2L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Pakistan = c(`0` = 2L, `1` = 2L, `2` = 4L, 
    `3` = 7L, `4` = 3L, NA, NA), Palestine = c(`2` = 1L, `3` = 2L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Panama = c(`0` = 1L, `1` = 3L, `2` = 1L, 
    `3` = 2L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA), Papua.New.Guinea = c(`1` = 1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Paraguay = c(`0` = 2L, `1` = 7L, 
    `2` = 14L, `3` = 11L, `4` = 10L, NA, NA), Peru = c(`0` = 1L, 
    `1` = 4L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 5L, `4` = 3L, NA, NA), Philippines = c(`0` = 4L, 
    `1` = 2L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 4L, `4` = 3L, NA, NA), Poland = c(`1` = 3L, 
    `2` = 2L, `3` = 8L, `4` = 25L, NA, NA, NA), Portugal = c(`1` = 2L, 
    `2` = 2L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 16L, NA, NA, NA), Qatar = c(`1` = 2L, 
    `2` = 2L, `3` = 6L, `4` = 10L, NA, NA, NA), Republic.of.Korea = c(`0` = 1L, 
    `1` = 3L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 5L, `4` = 11L, `6` = 1L, NA), Republic.of.Moldova = c(`1` = 1L, 
    `2` = 5L, `3` = 7L, `4` = 26L, NA, NA, NA), Romania = c(`0` = 1L, 
    `1` = 12L, `2` = 9L, `3` = 14L, `4` = 30L, `6` = 1L, NA), 
    Russian.Federation = c(`1` = 6L, `2` = 6L, `3` = 16L, `4` = 28L, 
    `6` = 3L, NA, NA), Rwanda = c(`5` = 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), Saint.Kitts.and.Nevis = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), Saint.Lucia = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Saint.Vincent.and.the.Grenadines = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_), Saudi.Arabia = c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 3L, `3` = 6L, 
    `4` = 4L, NA, NA, NA), Senegal = c(`2` = 4L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Serbia = c(`1` = 4L, `2` = 3L, `3` = 9L, 
    `4` = 29L, `6` = 2L, NA, NA), Sierra.Leone = c(`2` = 1L, 
    `3` = 1L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Singapore = c(`0` = 1L, 
    `1` = 1L, `2` = 3L, `3` = 4L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA), Slovakia = c(`1` = 1L, 
    `3` = 5L, `4` = 21L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Slovenia = c(`3` = 2L, 
    `4` = 19L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Somalia = c(`2` = 1L, `3` = 3L, 
    `4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), South.Africa = c(`0` = 3L, `1` = 4L, 
    `2` = 25L, `3` = 14L, `4` = 13L, `5` = 6L, NA), Spain = c(`1` = 6L, 
    `2` = 4L, `3` = 9L, `4` = 24L, NA, NA, NA), Sri.Lanka = c(`0` = 2L, 
    `2` = 1L, `3` = 2L, `4` = 7L, NA, NA, NA), Sudan = c(`2` = 1L, 
    `3` = 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Suriname = c(`1` = 2L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Sweden = c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 3L, 
    `4` = 15L, NA, NA, NA), Switzerland = c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 1L, 
    `3` = 1L, `4` = 17L, `5` = 1L, NA, NA), Syrian.Arab.Republic = c(`2` = 1L, 
    `3` = 2L, `4` = 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Tajikistan = c(`6` = 2L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Thailand = c(`0` = 4L, `1` = 4L, 
    `2` = 3L, `3` = 4L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA), Timor.Leste = c(`0` = 1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Trinidad.and.Tobago = c(`1` = 2L, 
    `2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Tunisia = c(`1` = 2L, 
    `2` = 1L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 5L, NA, NA, NA), Turkey = c(`1` = 9L, 
    `2` = 7L, `3` = 13L, `4` = 23L, `6` = 3L, NA, NA), Turkmenistan = c(`3` = 2L, 
    `4` = 1L, `6` = 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Uganda = c(`5` = 5L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Ukraine = c(`0` = 1L, `1` = 5L, 
    `2` = 14L, `3` = 16L, `4` = 30L, `6` = 3L, NA), United.Arab.Emirates = c(`1` = 1L, 
    `2` = 5L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 5L, NA, NA, NA), United.Kingdom.of.Great.Britain.and.Northern.Ireland = c(`1` = 2L, 
    `2` = 1L, `3` = 4L, `4` = 20L, NA, NA, NA), United.Republic.of.Tanzania = c(`2` = 1L, 
    `3` = 3L, `5` = 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA), United.States.of.America = structure(c(`0` = 4L, 
    `1` = 20L, `2` = 20L, `3` = 20L, `4` = 28L, `5` = 1L, `6` = 2L
    ), .Dim = 7L, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("0", "1", "2", 
    "3", "4", "5", "6")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), Uruguay = c(`2` = 1L, 
    `3` = 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Uzbekistan = c(`3` = 1L, `4` = 4L, 
    `6` = 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Venezuela..Bolivarian.Republic.of. = c(`1` = 2L, 
    `2` = 1L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 1L, NA, NA, NA), Viet.Nam = c(`0` = 3L, 
    `1` = 2L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 6L, `4` = 6L, `5` = 2L, NA), Yemen = c(`2` = 3L, 
    `3` = 4L, `4` = 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Zambia = c(`2` = 4L, 
    `5` = 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Zimbabwe = c(`2` = 1L, `4` = 1L, 
    `5` = 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA))

modules <- structure(list(Label = structure(1:169, .Label = c("Afghanistan", 
"Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", 
"Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", 
"Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", 
"Bhutan", "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", 
"Burundi", "C?te d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", 
"Central African Republic", "Chile", "China", "China, Hong Kong SAR", 
"China, Macao SAR", "China, Taiwan Province of", "Colombia", 
"Congo", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czechia", 
"Democratic People's Republic of Korea", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", 
"Denmark", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", 
"Eritrea", "Estonia", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", "Finland", "France", 
"Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", 
"Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", 
"Hungary", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", 
"Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", 
"Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", 
"Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Lithuania", 
"Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Malta", 
"Mauritania", "Mexico", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", 
"Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
"Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "North Macedonia", "Norway", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", 
"Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", 
"Republic of Korea", "Republic of Moldova", "Romania", "Russian Federation", 
"Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", 
"Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", 
"Tajikistan", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
"Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "United Republic of Tanzania", 
"United States of America", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", 
"Viet Nam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), 
    Degree = c(5L, 14L, 14L, 8L, 1L, 119L, 5L, 1L, 16L, 64L, 
    11L, 6L, 13L, 2L, 25L, 46L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 20L, 17L, 6L, 105L, 
    7L, 66L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 3L, 75L, 1L, 34L, 37L, 8L, 1L, 
    26L, 19L, 3L, 7L, 47L, 6L, 13L, 37L, 5L, 6L, 33L, 9L, 11L, 
    36L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 6L, 7L, 17L, 108L, 1L, 4L, 16L, 70L, 10L, 
    40L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 85L, 58L, 16L, 26L, 17L, 
    30L, 18L, 58L, 7L, 27L, 25L, 20L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 11L, 
    22L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 29L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 16L, 3L, 13L, 4L, 54L, 
    2L, 3L, 18L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 44L, 20L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 18L, 
    12L, 24L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 58L, 20L, 17L, 57L, 31L, 22L, 27L, 
    58L, 106L, 89L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 10L, 76L, 4L, 12L, 44L, 
    30L, 5L, 90L, 66L, 15L, 3L, 2L, 22L, 26L, 14L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 
    5L, 13L, 88L, 4L, 11L, 98L, 18L, 31L, 15L, 140L, 4L, 9L, 
    9L, 24L, 11L, 18L, 7L), modularity_class = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
    5L)), row.names = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", 
"Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", 
"Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
"Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", 
"Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", 
"Burundi", "C?te d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", 
"Central African Republic", "Chile", "China", "China, Hong Kong SAR", 
"China, Macao SAR", "China, Taiwan Province of", "Colombia", 
"Congo", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czechia", 
"Democratic People's Republic of Korea", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", 
"Denmark", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", 
"Eritrea", "Estonia", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", "Finland", "France", 
"Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", 
"Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", 
"Hungary", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", 
"Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", 
"Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", 
"Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Lithuania", 
"Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Malta", 
"Mauritania", "Mexico", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", 
"Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
"Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "North Macedonia", "Norway", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", 
"Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", 
"Republic of Korea", "Republic of Moldova", "Romania", "Russian Federation", 
"Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", 
"Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", 
"Tajikistan", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
"Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "United Republic of Tanzania", 
"United States of America", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", 
"Viet Nam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you limit your data to `dput(head(list))` it's much easier to copy.

Comment: how do you compute degree and modularity_class?

Comment: There is no such thing as `list$Value` in the posted data, `list` is a list of countries.

Comment: If I am understanding the formula, for each country, sum the values in `list` and divide by `modules$Degree` of that country. Is this it?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I would like to divide each value in ```list``` by ```modules@Degree```, and sum them. Hope clearer in my updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not *entirely* sure what you want to do — but as a first step it would help to merge all your data into a single table. You can do this with a list column:

```
nodes = data.frame(Label = names(list))
nodes$Nodes = list # Needs to be set separately
table = merge(modules, nodes, by = 'Label')
```

(Note that this drops some rows where the country names differ between your two data sources; this could presumably be cleaned up but I didn’t do this here.)

Now you could implement your equation. If I’m understanding correctly, P<sub>i</sub> is just

```
p = function (nodes, degree) {
    1 - sum((nodes / degree) ^ 2, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

And to apply this to all rows, you could use

```
table$Result = vapply(
    seq_len(nrow(table)),
    function (i) p(table$Nodes[[i]], table$Degree[i]),
    numeric(1L)
)
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a million, this seems to work perfectly and I will check the results in detail. I only wonder what you mean by # Needs to be set separately?

Comment: @MoonS The relevant code is first creating a `data.frame` and then adding a new column for the nodes. Why not create the nodes in the `data.frame` call? Because the `Nodes` column is a [list column](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls13_list-columns.html), and the `data.frame` function does not support list columns. That’s why it needs to be set in a separate assignment.

Comment: Yes I see. Thanks so much again!

Comment: I noticed that p currently calculates the sum of nodes/total degree, but it should rather sum a (node's links to a given module/its total degree) for all modules. E.g. for Indonesia, rather than summing (5+4+3+1)/16, it should sum (5/16+4/16+3/16+1/16). Is there a way to update this? @Konrad Rudolph

Comment: @MoonS The two operations are identical via distributivity of division. (a + b) / c = a/c + b/c (strictly speaking, floating point arithmetic might lead to very slight differences in these two operations but if this is a relevant issue for you then you have much bigger problems that won’t be easily solvable by restating the equation, unfortunately. In practice, it *shouldn’t* be an issue.

Comment: Many thanks for replying so quickly. I just don't see why I, when double-checking the calculation for Indonesia in Excel, get 0,80 from 1-((5/16)^2+(4/16)^2+(3/16)^2+(1/16)^2) compared to 0,339 from 1-(((5+4+3+1)/16)^2). Maybe I make some trivial error? @Konrad Rudolph

Comment: I'm also not sure why e.g. Luxembourg would get -3 instead of 0?

Comment: @MoonS Ah, because squaring changes things: ((a + b) / c) ^ 2 ≠ (a/c)^2 + (b/c)^2. I made a mistake with the operator precedence of the exponentiation — fixed now. As for Luxembourg, I don’t understand how you’re expecting to get 0. -3 is the correct answer: Luxembourg has a single link, of value 2. 1 - (2/1)^2 = -3.

Comment: @MoonS Actually, your values for Indonesia are also different from the data you gave in the question: Indonesia’s node values are 3, 3, 3, 3, 1; not 5, 4, 3, 1.

Comment: @MoonS OK, then I don’t understand your data, as indicated at the beginning of my answer: what does `k_is` actually correspond to in your data? I thought it was the values in in `list`.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment because I was working with updated data. And yes, you're right about the values, forget my previous confusion. I however noticed an issue with my list in that it adds the focal node as a link too. That's a separate question, but if you have a simple answer on how to deal with that I would be very grateful. In any case, thanks so much!